# ElasticSearch Snapshot: reasons for partial status

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-snapshot

I'm not sure the reason for my snapshots are PARTIAL suddenly, till yesterday it was SUCCESS and how to debug this.

Any help?

Comment: To get info, use `GET /_snapshot/your_backup_repo/your_snapshot_id`. Then, check the `failure` section to debug

Comment: @glenacota, this is what I'm seeing as failure reason, `IndexShardSnapshotFailedException[Failed to finalize snapshot creation [snapshot_name/jIkkonhrWUxTd9Dnqhg_tg] with shard index [index-0]]; nested: FileAlreadyExistsException[Blob [index-0] already exists, cannot overwrite];` But I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: FYI, I'm trying to use the same S3 bucket for manual snapshots for 2 different ElasticSearch instances, will it cause any issues?